# Setting flags such as `-n', `-r', `-l' with `org-babel-default-header-args'

Tags: org-babel

As in the title; I'm wondering whether the cell cars will be keywords, strings, or quoted values, and the cdr will be booleans, such as in the following cases:

```
(setq org-babel-default-header-args
      (cons '(:n . t)
            (assq-delete-all :n org-babel-default-header-args)))

;; OR

(setq org-babel-default-header-args
      (cons '("n" . t)
            (assq-delete-all "n" org-babel-default-header-args)))

;; OR

(setq org-babel-default-header-args
      (cons '('n . t)
            (assq-delete-all 'n org-babel-default-header-args)))
```

Comment: Did any of these work? My understanding is that switches like `-n`, `-l`, `-r` are separate from header args and cannot be set the same way. But I would not be surprised to be proved wrong.

Comment: I don't know a good test for them, unfortunately; any ideas?